# Re-arranging an equation help

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I re-arrange the equation
$$
-150 = (-9.8)(t) + 0.5(-9.8)(t)^2
$$
and solve for $t$?

I collected the like terms firstly, so

$$-150 = -48.02 \cdot t^3$$

then I knew I was doing something wrong.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to solve for the value $t$

Comment: are you adding two terms OR multiplying?

Comment: Where did you get the $t^3$ from??? And what does "like terms" mean?

Comment: I want to solve for T in the above

Comment: @barakmanos my horrible algebra skills thats where

Comment: @roflfl Is it necessary for you to work with decimals? It may be easier for you to work with fractions here.

Comment: dude you are multiplying things on the right you arent rearranging them.... and moreover even if you multiply you have a negative sign on the right... which is wrong

Comment: @Jasser May be more helpful to point things out than to make light of the algebraic issues the OP is facing.

Comment: thankyou I appreciate that @induktio... and the points i have pointed might be helpful for OP to correct things out..

Comment: @roflfl Maybe my answer will make it clearer for you now :)

Comment: @Jasser Maybe my answer will help clear things up now, but if rearranging the equation is an issue, then I imagine my answer may be hard to digest. I'm not sure how to make it much simpler though.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the $-9.8$ is really giving you some troubles. It may help to temporarily make a substitution by letting $m=-9.8$. Then your equation
$$
-150 = (-9.8)(t)+0.5(-9.8)(t)^2
$$
becomes
$$
-150=mt+0.5(m)(t)^2\Longleftrightarrow -150=tm+\frac{m}{2}t^2\Longleftrightarrow mt^2+2mt+300=0.
$$
As noted before, you are dealing with a *quadratic*. Assuming you know the quadratic formula or at least have access to it (I present it below), we see that for a general quadratic of the form 
$$
ax^2+bx+c=0,
$$
whose solutions are given by
$$
x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a},
$$
we have that, for our own quadratic, that

- $a = m$
- $b = 2m$
- $c = 300$

Thus, the solutions for $t$ will be given by
$$
t = \frac{-2m\pm\sqrt{(2m)^2-4(m)(300)}}{2m} = \frac{-m\pm\sqrt{m^2-300}}{m}.
$$
Now, recall that we have $m=-9.8$. Substitute this value into the rightmost equation above and you will have your answers for $t$.

Comment: what i meant was that... it might be easy for us to see the kinematic equation of OP. But what if OP is not working with kinematics, he might get more confused...I thought it this way...

Comment: You can help OP even more by editing your answer this way by telling that if a=b then $a-c=b-c$ then showing him the rearrangement... and yes you are good at latex

Comment: Only so much you can do. I've done too much as it is. I'm gonna go eat a banana or something. G'night world.

Answer (score 1):

First, let us look at the equation this way:

$\frac{1}{2}(-9.8)t^2-(9.8)t+150=0$.

Do you see it is in the form $ax^2+bx+c=0$?

From here you should be able to use the quadratic formula and take the positive root since time should not be negative.

Comment: Is there an easier way to do this without quadratic? I wanted to solve for it you are correct

Comment: how do you know that the variable t here refers to time here?

Comment: This looks like kinematics to me. It may be naive to assume it to be such.

Comment: I agree with @Krampus. The $-9.8$ is *highly* suggestive of $g$.

Comment: oh yes @krampus 9.8